# How do you configure cells to work with a different url root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells

My Rails 3.2 application runs under `http://localhost/my-app`. Without anything special, the `image_url` helper figures this out correctly:

```
<%= image_tag("test.png") %> #=> <img src="/my-app/assets/test.png" alt="Test">
```

However, when that same helper method is called from a cell, the url loses `/my-app`.

```
<%= image_tag("test.png") %> #=> <img src="/assets/test.png" alt="Test">
```

That of course results in a 404 response.

**How to I properly configure cells to work with a different root url?**

I've tried setting `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/my-app"`, but that had no effect.

Here are the relevant bits needed to reproduce this:

```
# /app/cells/foo_cell.rb
class FooCell < Cell::Base  
  def test
    render
  end
end

# /app/cells/foo/test.html.erb
<%= image_tag("test.png") %>

# Somewhere in /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= image_tag("test.png") %>
<%= render_cell(:foo, :test) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to include the full path in the `image_tag` call:

```
<%= image_tag("/my-app/assets/test.png") %>
```